# drawing png to SpriteBatch is not working

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, monogame, spritebatch

I just started working on `MonoGame` , and I was just trying to load simple `Sprite` at the `Game` class as follow :

```
public class Main : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D test;

        public Main()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory ="Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            test =  Content.Load<Texture2D>("default");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// game-specific content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(test, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

but it's not working , what am missing here?

Comment: What do you mean it's "not working"? Are you getting an error or just not seeing your sprite on the screen?

Comment: I can't see my sprite on the screen

Comment: This looks like it should be working. Do you see the background painted to `Color.CornflowerBlue` at all? Are you sure that you have a texture named `default.png` in your content project, and that it's configured to be imported (Build action: "Compile", Content importer/processor set to "Texture - XNA framework" or "Monogame texture")?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you're passing a class to the `SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice device)` constructor instead of an instance of it.

Try replacing `spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);` with `spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics.GraphicsDevice);`.

I've also had a little trouble getting alpha channels to work in MonoGame, using `spriteBatch.Begin ((SpriteSortMode)0, BlendState.NonPremultiplied)` worked for me.

Comment: I did exactly what you just recommended but it didn't work, do I have to use `MonoGame PipleLine`?

Comment: I just attempted to rubberduck-debug your code with no result, so I decided to copy it over to a MonoGame DirectX template, turns out it works for me, are you sure you have the Content folder inside of your currently selected build environment's folder? (And no, you don't *have* to use the Pipeline)

Comment: well am using `MonoGame Cross Platform Desktop Project` , maybe that's why? the `Texture` is being loaded with no issue at all , when I debug it I can see it's successfully loaded it , but it doesn't draw it

Comment: Possibly, for some reason I'm not able to create a `MonoGame Cross Platform Desktop Project` in Xamarin Studio (Licensing perhaps?) so I'm afraid I can't test that for you.

Comment: `GraphicsDevice` is a property of the base `Game` class so the code is valid as far as I can tell. Replacing it with `graphics.GraphicsDevice` wouldn't make any difference here.

Comment: True, I didn't realise that as in the tutorial series I followed for XNA I've learned to use graphics.GraphicsDevice, which shouldn't be any different as it is probably just a pointer to Game.GraphicsDevice.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to specify the type of image file you are loading, try adding ".png" to the end of "default". Because you said the image is being loaded correctly, this may not fix your issue, but I suggest trying it.

If that does not work, the problem may be with your OS and the version of Monogame and or Visual Studio; I've had problems with images not being drawn but everything else compiling with conflicting versions and settings in Visual Studio. Hope that helps!